# Obtain a safe value on a function with switch in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, switch-statement, type-safety

I have a function that takes an argument that can have 3 different values.
This function returns a value according to the argument, so it can return three different values.

So I use a switch, which compares the argument to determine the value to return. So I have a safe value for each possible values of the argument.

However if I call the function with an argument, the returned value is not certain, TypeScript keeps the possibility of the other 2 values.

```js
function get(value: "string" | "number" | "boolean") {
    switch (value) {
        case "string": 
            return "A";
        case "number": 
            return 1;
        case "boolean": 
            return true;
    }
}

var test1 = get("number");
```

[image]

So how to have safe values? Do I have to go through an enumeration? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use generics instead, in combination with an object that maps `value`s to the return value:

```
const map = {
    string: 'A',
    number: 1,
    boolean: true,
};
type MapType = typeof map;
function get<T extends keyof MapType>(value: T) {
    return map[value];
}

var test1 = get("number");
```

If you want the return type to be *exact* - eg not just `number`, but `1` - then declare the map `as const` to avoid the automatic widening:

```
const map = {
    string: 'A',
    number: 1,
    boolean: true,
} as const;
```